# How to ask multiple permissions in a react-native application?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Right now I am building an applications which uses multiple device features like location, camera, storage and contacts. 
I want to know if there is any way that allows users to enter into my application if and only if all the permissions are granted.

I've tried using [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions) and the code snippet is as follows

```
Permissions.request('photo').then(() => {
  Permissions.request('location').then(() => {
    Permissions.request('camera').then(() => {
      Permissions.request('contacts').then(() => {
        Permissions.request('notification').then(() => {
          console.log('PERMISSIONS ASKED');
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The above code works only at the first time and if the user clicks **deny** then it is not asking again. Can any one help me with this.

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once a user denies a permission he won't be asked for the permission again(iOS). He have to go back to settings and manually update the permissions.

It is not a good practice to ask all the permissions at once, the right way to ask is to alert for the permission when user initiate the usage of services like (location, camera).

Any way if you would like to ask all the permissions at once then you can check if the permission is in denied state, if so you can show an alert to open settings and change the permission.

```
Permissions.check('location', { type: 'always' }).then(response => {
  this.setState({ locationPermission: response })
})
```